# How to solve the constrained convex optimization problem with nuclear norm?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nuclear-norm

Let $f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{ij}+\sqrt{-1}y_{ij})B_{ij}(x,y)$

Now I want to solve the following problem:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
     &\arg\min_{C} \iint_{[0,1]^2}|(f_x+\sqrt{-1}f_y)-g(f_x-\sqrt{-1}f_y)|^2\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y+\omega\|C\|_{*}\\
         s.t. \quad &C_{i1},C_{in},C_{1j},C_{nj}\quad (i=1,\cdots,n;j=1,\cdots,n)\quad \text{are given}.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Where $C\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a complex matrix with the following form:
$$
      \begin{equation}
       C=\left(
       \begin{array}{cccc} 
        x_{11}+\sqrt{-1}y_{11} & x_{12}+\sqrt{-1}y_{12} & \cdots &x_{1n}+\sqrt{-1}y_{1n} \\
        x_{21}+\sqrt{-1}y_{21} & x_{22}+\sqrt{-1}y_{22} & \cdots &x_{2n}+\sqrt{-1}y_{2n} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \vdots \\
x_{n1}+\sqrt{-1}y_{n1} & x_{n2}+\sqrt{-1}y_{n2} & \cdots &x_{nn}+\sqrt{-1}y_{nn}
       \end{array}
       \right)
=X+\sqrt{-1}Y
        \end{equation}
$$

$g=sin(xy)+\sqrt{-1}cos(x+y)$, and $\|\cdot\|_{*}$ is the nuclear norm of a matrix.

How to solve this convex problem?

I convert this problrm into  the following form:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
     &\arg\min_{C} \frac{1}{2}c^TAc+\omega\|C\|_{*}\\
         s.t. \quad &x_{i1},y_{i1},x_{in},y_{in},x_{1j},y_{1j},x_{nj},y_{nj}\quad (i=1,\cdots,n;j=1,\cdots,n)\quad \text{are given}.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
where $A$ is a real positive-definite matrix, $c$ is a combination of the vectorization of $X$ and $Y$ which is defined as: $c=(\text{vec}(X),\text{vec}(Y))$.

But I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest approach is to simply use a modelling tool (YALMIP, CVX etc) with any semidefinite programming solver (Mosek, Sedumi,SDPT3 etc). It is a fairly standard problem.

Here is the corresponding YALMIP code (MATLAB modelling toolbox)

```
X = sdpvar(n,n,'full');
Y = sdpvar(n,n,'full');
C = X + sqrt(-1)*Y
c = [X(:);Y(:)];
Model = [X(:,1) == values,Y(:,1) == someothervalues,...];
optimize(Model,c'*A*c + norm(C,'nuclear');
```

Comment: How to use ADMM to solve this problem?

Comment: If you are lazy, you simply use the ADMM solver https://github.com/giofantuzzi/CDCS which is supported in YALMIP. If you want to implement ADMM on your own (to actually exploit nuclear norm structure), I really don't understand the purpose of the question, as it should be obvious how to solve the problem, if you have sufficient insight in the field to implement an ADMM solver for the problem

Comment: I really don't know how to solve this problem by ADMM. I solved the classical matrix completion problem before, but I think the question I propose here is a bit different, as the variable $\mathbf{c}$ is real, however, the matrix $\mathcal{C}$ is complex. I don't know how to do the variable splitting.

Comment: You don't have to split the variables. $c^TAc$ is going to be equivalent to some alternative form $\bar{c}^H \bar{A} \bar{c}$, where $\bar{c}=\mathop{\textrm{vec}}(X+iY)$, and $\bar{A}$ is Hermitian.

Comment: A is a real positive-definite matrix, How to transform $c^{T}Ac$ into the alternative form $\bar{c}^H\bar{A}\bar{c}$? I use the method of indetermined coefficients to solve $\bar{A}$, but I can't get the solution.

Comment: I try to use the software "YALMIP" to solve this problem, but it often gets the INFEASIBLE solution, I don't know why. I write a test code like this:
    x = randn(4,1)
y = randn(4,1)
M = diag(rand(32,1));
U = orth(rand(32,32));
A = U' * M * U;
X = sdpvar(4,4,'full');
Y = sdpvar(4,4,'full');
C = X + sqrt(-1)*Y
c = [X(:);Y(:)];
Constraints = [X(:,1) == x,Y(:,1) == y];
optimize(Constraints,c'*A*c + norm(C,'nuclear'));

Comment: You may be right, for general $A$ you may not be able to find an equivalent $\bar{A}$. But I strongly suspect that your problem didn't start out this way: that is, I suspect that the original form of this problem involved the complex matrices, and you (or someone else) tried to convert it half-way into an equivalent real form. What I would suggest is that you edit this question to present the *original* problem being solved, involving only $C$ itself.

Comment: Yes, I've converted the original problem, now the original problem is presented above.

Comment: why do you still continue to insist on separating the real and imaginary parts? just use complex variables.

Comment: Yes, I also want to use the complex variables. But in the original optimization model, how to deal with $\iint_{[0,1]^2}|(f_x+\sqrt{-1}f_y)-g(f_x-\sqrt{-1}f_y)|^2\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$? as the modulus of a complex number is real.